# Unresponsive Samsung Galaxy S6 phone, even to soft reset (volume down + power)

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I'm having some trouble with my Samsung Galaxy S6 not responding.

I can't remember which Android version it has; it's whatever it came with in 2015, so it's Marshmallow or earlier. The phone is not rooted, not modified. I think that USB debugging is enabled.

The phone is showing a slowly blinking blue notification light.

It does not respond to pressing any of the keys, does not respond to soft reset (volume down + power), does not respond to hard reset (volume up + power + home).

When plugged into a computer via USB cable the computer does not give the option to connect to the phone.

Running "adb devices" at the (Ubuntu) command line with phone connected returns blank list of devices.

What are my options? Is there some other reset option I haven't yet tried?